# Make a loop for a JS-function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JS-function for an array with image's and alt's for a HTML class which shows the image src with a caption from the alt.
onclick, the function shows the next picture and stops at the last picture.
Now i want that the last picture is linked to the first picture.
I'll try it on my own but any help is welcome.

here is my code :

```js
const createImage = (image, alt, index) => {
  return `<img src="${image}" alt="${alt}" class="img-thumbnail border-0 img-thumbnail-desktop" onClick="expandingImage(this)" currentimage="${index}"/>`;
};

// Logic
const createImages = (images) => {
  let final = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    const e = images[i];
    final += createImage(e.image, e.alt, i);
  }
  return final;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  console.log('Loaded')

  const container = document.querySelector('.thumbnailContainer');

  container.innerHTML = createImages(imagesArr)
});

const nextImage = (img) => {
  const current = +img.getAttribute('currentimage');
  if (current < imagesArr.length - 1) {
    img.setAttribute('src', imagesArr[current + 1].image)
    img.setAttribute('alt', imagesArr[current + 1].alt)
    img.setAttribute('currentimage', current + 1)
    document.querySelector("#imgtext").innerHTML = imagesArr[current + 1].alt
  }
}

function expandingImage(imgs) {
  const expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
  const imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
  expandImg.src = imgs.src;
  imgText.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
  expandImg.setAttribute("currentimage", imgs.getAttribute('currentimage'))
  expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  const imagesArr = [{
      image: '#####',
      alt: ''
    }, {
      image: '#####',
      alt: ''
    },
    {
      image: '#####',
      alt: ''
    },

  ];
</script>

<div class="col-md-9 ">

  <!--START MAIN CONTENT-->
  <div class="hideMobile">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'"></span>
      <img class="img-fluid img-overlay" id="expandedImg" src="#####">
    </div>
    <div class="container expandedImgSize d-flex justify-content-center" id="imgtext">
      <figcaption class="figure-caption">Caption</figcaption>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--END MAIN CONTENT-->
```

Comment: Your question isn't  clear.

Comment: You're expected to try it on your own *before* asking on Stack Overflow. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please include a [**minimal**, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) along with what you've tried, what happened, and how it differs from what you're expecting to happen.

Comment: your code sample has error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')"

Answer (score 0):

Use modular arithmetic to wrap around the next image number to 0 when you reach the end of the array.

```js
const imagesArr = [{
    image: '#####',
    alt: ''
  }, {
    image: '#####',
    alt: ''
  },
  {
    image: '#####',
    alt: ''
  },
];

const createImage = (image, alt, index) => {
  return `<img src="${image}" alt="${alt}" class="img-thumbnail border-0 img-thumbnail-desktop" onClick="expandingImage(this)" currentimage="${index}"/>`;
};

// Logic
const createImages = (images) => {
  let final = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    const e = images[i];
    final += createImage(e.image, e.alt, i);
  }
  return final;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  console.log('Loaded')

  const container = document.querySelector('.thumbnailContainer');
  container.innerHTML = createImages(imagesArr)
});

const nextImage = (img) => {
  const current = +img.getAttribute('currentimage');
  let next = (current + 1) % imagesArr.length;
  img.setAttribute('src', imagesArr[next].image)
  img.setAttribute('alt', imagesArr[next].alt)
  img.setAttribute('currentimage', next)
  document.querySelector("#imgtext").innerHTML = imagesArr[next].alt
}

function expandingImage(imgs) {
  const expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
  const imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
  expandImg.src = imgs.src;
  imgText.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
  expandImg.setAttribute("currentimage", imgs.getAttribute('currentimage'))
  expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-9 ">

  <!--START MAIN CONTENT-->
  <div class="hideMobile">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'"></span>
      <img class="img-fluid img-overlay" id="expandedImg" src="#####">
    </div>
    <div class="container expandedImgSize d-flex justify-content-center" id="imgtext">
      <figcaption class="figure-caption">Caption</figcaption>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--END MAIN CONTENT-->
```